# java.io.IOException: Wrong index checksum, store was not closed properly and could be corrupted

Tags: queue, commit, checksum, mapdb

I encountered the exception after restarting Jetty, which contains producer-consumer implementation via MapDB's Queue. I haven't call "DBMaker.transactionDisable()", but why did I still get the above exceptions?

Before I restarted Jetty, I found the consumer seems blocked. By jstack command, I got lots of following logs:

> "qtp1730704097-270" #270 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7b60006800
>   nid=0xb44f waiting on condition [0x00007f7986ae9000]
>   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)   at
>   sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>     - parking to wait for  <0x000000054047c420> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(BlockingArrayQueue.java:342)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.idleJobPoll(QueuedThreadPool.java:526)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.access$600(QueuedThreadPool.java:44)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>     - None

Here are some code fragment:

```
// Consumer code:

public void run() {
    try {
        while (!stopped) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastCheckTime > 60000) {
                localDb.commit();
                localDb.compact();
                lastCheckTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            ...
            for (...) {
                queue.poll();
            }
            ...
            localDb.commit();
        }
        localDb.commit();
        localDb.compact();
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        LOG.error("", ie);
    }
}

// Others code:

...
DB localDb = DBMaker.newFileDB(new File(path)).closeOnJvmShutdown().make();
localDb.catPut(QUEUE_NAME + ".useLocks", false);
queue = localDb.getQueue(QUEUE_NAME);
...

public void interrupt() {
    stopped = true;
    localDb.close();
}
```

java -version: java version "1.8.0_11"

Thanks!